# If parent element has only 2 child elements do something, else something else

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this html markup:

```
<div class="buttons-holder>
    <label class="my-btn">
        <input name="example" value="1" type="radio"> YES
    </label>
    <label class="my-btn">
        <input name="example" value="0" checked="checked" type="radio"> NO
    </label>
</div>
```

But sometimes I have more than one label inside the `.buttons-holder` element. How can I specify in jQuery to apply my jQuery code only if there exists 2 label elements?

I tried something like this but it still applies to all elements:

```
    if ($('form label:has(input[type="radio"])').eq(2)) { 
        //do something 
    } else {
        //do something else
    }
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jw51hggc/

Comment: you need to check for length like `$('form label:has(input[type="radio"])').length > 1`

Comment: Tried that but no luck. http://jsfiddle.net/jw51hggc/

Comment: what is it that you are trying to do

Comment: to wrap the labels only if the parent element of labels has only 2  labels.

Comment: if there are 3 labels what to do?

Comment: Nothing for now,just want to apply it only if exists 2 labels.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yg73syx7/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60978/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-eddi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments and fiddle

```
$('form .buttons-holder').filter(function(){
    return $(this).children('label:has(input[type="radio"])').length == 2
}).wrapInner('<div class="wrap"></div>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yg73syx7/)